# Postorder traversal of nested dom elements selected by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tree-traversal

This should be a nice little puzzle, and hopefully solvable by jQuery. Here is a [self explanatory jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/tMkZn/5/). Note that I am looking for a generic solution to traverse the elements of interest in the dom based on where they are in the dom tree. I provide this reduced case as an example, so you can test your solutions against it and it is also easier to understand.

The DOM:

```
<div class="element" value="Hi5!">
    <div class="element" value="Zero"></div>
    <div class="junk" value="no no!"></div>
    <div class="element" value="Four">
        <div class="element" value="One"></div>
        <div class="element" value="Three">
            <div class="element" value="Two"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element" value="Five"></div>
</div>
```

The code I'v got which prints elements in an undesired order:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready");
    $(".element").each(function(index, item){
       console.log(index + " | ",  item.getAttribute('value'));
    });
});
```

The current output:

```
ready
0 | Hi5!
1 | Zero
2 | Two
3 | One
4 | Four
5 | Three
6 | Five
```

How can I traverse and print the values of the nested div elements above in a [postorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Postorder) fashion?

Edit: thanks to @zshooter for providing a solution and pointing out a mistake in my question. Here is my [updated jsFiddle ordered properly in postorder.](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/tMkZn/7/)

Comment: So to be _really_ clear, your desired output is...?

Comment: well, lets say if you solve it, it looks very natural ;)

Comment: Do the indices matter or can they be dropped?

Comment: Very natural? So you want "five, four, three, two, one, zero, Hi5!".

Comment: I put the indices to show the desired order. If you want to drop them, sure go ahead. As long as the output is in correct order: zero, one, two ... you know.

Comment: ok ok :P no I want: zero one two three four five Hi5!

Comment: number order isn't quite postorder in this example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/pr7v9/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready");

    $("body").children('.element').each(function(index, item) {
        visitNode(item);
    });
});

function visitNode(element) {
    $(element).children('.element').each(function(index, item) {
        visitNode(item);
    });
    console.log(element.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

Comment: looks promising, but I get no output in console from the fiddle, did you update the fiddle?

Comment: oh no wait, I get zero one three ... instead of zero one two. something missing?

Comment: nope, the order is correct, 2 is parent of 1 & 4 so should come after

Comment: I fixed the question with proper postorder order. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An answer has already been given, but I wrote a more generic function:

```
function applyPostOrder(selector, fn, filter)
{
    (function visit() {
        $node = jQuery(this);
        $node.children(filter).each(visit);

        if (!filter || $node.is(filter)) {
            fn(this);
        }
    }).call(jQuery(selector).get(0));
}
```

This function will call `fn` for every node found that matches the given filter. This is how you call it:

```
function visitItem(node)
{
    console.log(node.getAttribute('value'));
}

jQuery(function($) {
    console.log("ready");
    applyPostOrder('body', visitItem, '.element');
});
```